# pd.fillna replacement value not appearing in correct position in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, fillna

I am very new to python and trying to fill NaN values in a very large csv file with a space using pd.fillna but the spaces all appear at the end of each row with NaN values. Code is listed below.

```
reader = pd.read_csv(path, sep='\s+', skipinitialspace=True, dtype=str, engine='python', names=headers)
spacedReader = reader.fillna(value=' ', axis=1)
spacedReader.to_csv(path, sep=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=' ', header=headers)
```

```
001  alb  272  nc      
002  NaN  NaN  nc
NaN  alb  768  nc
```

will produce...

```
001,alb,272,nc
002,nc, , 
alb,768,nc,
```

And I need...

```
001,alb,272,nc
002, , , nc
 ,alb,768,nc
```

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: _but it does not work._ What does that mean, exactly? Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Comment: Just updated with an example output.

Comment: @clt2stanford if my solution was useful can you select my answer as the best asnwer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 2, np.nan, 0],
                   [3, 4, np.nan, 1],
                   [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5],
                   [np.nan, 3, np.nan, 4]],
                  columns=list('ABCD'))


df1 = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)

df1.head()
```

output

```
    A   B   C   D
0       2       0
1   3   4       1
2               5
3       3       4
```